# Beachy Head Suicide Spot, Chaplaincy Donation?

Tags: safety, nature-and-wildlife, england

I will be guiding several visitors to Beachy Head to see the dramatic views and to stand on the clifftop and experience the North Sea wind.  Unfortunately, the best viewing spot is also a renowned suicide venue.  The cliffs are not set off by fences or walls and it's a 530 straight drop to the rocks below.

[image]

While there I want to make a small donation to the chaplaincy team that patrols the area looking for despondent/missing/suicidal people.  Is there a donation box? Or some other receptacle where one can leave a cash donation?  I'm sure there's a way to do this somewhere on the net by using a credit card or PayPal, but the experience would be more enriching if one can leave a modest anonymous donation **in person, 'in situ'** **'ex tempore'**, right then and there; say GBP 20 as an indicative amount.

I also know there's a duty chaplain I could ask, but they may be on patrol or otherwise engaged. I have also telephoned them but the admin lines were not attended to.

**Question**: is there a box, or bucket, or bin where one can make a donation to the chaplaincy team? I am sure there's a way via the net but that's not what this is about.

**Secondarily**: is there any way to get to the lighthouse by foot? A place where there are stairs or it's otherwise safe to climb down and walk along the sea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a [street address](http://www.bhct.org.uk/wp/contact-us-2/) for the chaplaincy. It is:

```
Beachy Head Chaplaincy Team
Trinity Centre,
Trinity Place,
Eastbourne East Sussex UK BN21 3BX
```

You could try swinging by that location during normal business hours and see if anyone would be willing to take a donation. If there isn't anyone there, you could probably slip an envelope with some cash and a note under the door.

Regarding the lighthouse, here's a [Tweet](https://twitter.com/BHChaplaincy/status/807309524789030912) released by the Beachy Head Chaplaincy with a photo of the lighthouse. It clearly shows that there are some steps, a dock, or something similar leading out from the lighthouse toward the shore. In that pic, there seem to be enough rocks that one could make it the rest of the way to shore. Perhaps this is a low-tide pic, so the lighthouse might only be accessible then.

[image]
[Source: Beachy Head Chaplaincy Tweet](https://twitter.com/BHChaplaincy/status/807309524789030912)

Comment: There's a Virgin Money Donate Here button on that page; it leads here (for a one-off, rather than reoccuring donaton)

https://uk.virginmoneygiving.com/fundraiser-web/donate/makeDonationForCharityDisplay.action?charityId=1007726&frequencyType=S

You can donate by Visa/Mastercard/Amex/PayPal.